# why ssh myLogin@localhost works but ssh root@localhost doesn't?

Tags: ssh, root

I know ssh root@localhost is a bad idea...I get it.

But why doesn't `ssh root@localhost` work?

I even changed my root password just in case:

```
> sudo -s
> passwd
```

But still when I do `ssh root@localhost` I get

`root@localhost's password`: [I enter the password]

`Permission denied, please try again.`

---

I tried ssh -v not sure what to look for here are the final few lines:

```
...
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myName/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myName/.ssh/id_abcde
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myName/.ssh/id_ed123456
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@localhost's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password                                                                                                                                     
Permission denied, please try again.                                                                                                                                                              
root@localhost's password:                                                                                                                                                                        
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password                                                                                                                                     
Permission denied, please try again.                                                                                                                                                              
root@localhost's password:                                                                                                                                                                        
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password                                                                                                                                     
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.                                                                                                                                                    
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

---

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Comment: Try verbose  `ssh -v`

Comment: grep  root /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: did you set `PermitRootLogin yes` ?

Comment: @RobertL - update the ticket -v output

Comment: @lese  please see updated question

Comment: @muru please look at updated question...thanks!

Comment: @muru yes i did - changed the file to yes and saved it but it is still asking for password

Comment: @muru after changing the parameter to yes I had to restart ssh: service ssh restart  - Not it works thank you!

Comment: Is the output of `ssh -v` the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

According to the sshd_config [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> **PermitRootLogin**
>   Specifies whether root can log in using ssh(1).  The argument
>   must be “yes”, “without-password”, “forced-commands-only”, or
>   “no”.  The default is “yes”.
>   If this option is set to “without-password”, password authentication is ***disabled*** for root.

The `without-password` setting is mainly useful for logging in using a public key (in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).